# PyQt QScrollBar.setInvertedControls() has no effect

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I a making PyQt5 GUI application where I need to show a vertical QScrollBar in an inverted shape (zero below and max above).
Calling `setInvertedAppearance(True)` is enough to show it properly. However, the controls still behave as usual (clicking the down arrow **increases** the value, which goes **UP**, and vise versa).

Calling `setInvertedControls()` does not seem to have any effect!

Comment: With "arrow" do you mean the keys on your keyboard, or the buttons at the extremities of the scroll bar?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: As per the docs, the [invertedControls](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#invertedControls-prop) property only affects wheel and key events. Looking at the source code for QScrollBar confirms that the mouse-press/release events don't reference this property at all (and the same goes for `invertedAppearance`). So, the property *does* have an effect - just not what you were expecting.